# CIFilter black and white image appears blue after blending

Tags: swift, mask, cifilter, ciimage

I'm getting unexpected results when applying CIFilters to an image. The expected result is a black and white image with the color orange blending through the edges. Instead I get a blue-ish image with red blending through the edges. My function is:

```
func sketch(with ciImage: CIImage) -> CIImage {

    var sourceCore = ciImage

    var convolutionValue_A:CGFloat = -0.0925937220454216
    var convolutionValue_B:CGFloat = -0.4166666567325592
    var convolutionValue_C:CGFloat = -1.8518532514572144
    var convolutionValue_D:CGFloat = 0.23148006200790405
    var convolutionValue_E:CGFloat = 4.5833334922790527
    var convolutionValue_F:CGFloat = 14.166666984558105

    var brightnessVal:CGFloat = 1.1041666269302368
    var contrastVal:CGFloat = 3.0555555820465088

    var weightsArr: [CGFloat] = [
        convolutionValue_A, convolutionValue_A, convolutionValue_B, convolutionValue_B, convolutionValue_B, convolutionValue_A, convolutionValue_A,
        convolutionValue_A, convolutionValue_B, convolutionValue_C, convolutionValue_C, convolutionValue_C, convolutionValue_B, convolutionValue_A,
        convolutionValue_B, convolutionValue_C, convolutionValue_D, convolutionValue_E, convolutionValue_D, convolutionValue_C, convolutionValue_B,
        convolutionValue_B, convolutionValue_C, convolutionValue_E, convolutionValue_F, convolutionValue_E, convolutionValue_C, convolutionValue_B,
        convolutionValue_B, convolutionValue_C, convolutionValue_D, convolutionValue_E, convolutionValue_D, convolutionValue_C, convolutionValue_B,
        convolutionValue_A, convolutionValue_B, convolutionValue_C, convolutionValue_C, convolutionValue_C, convolutionValue_B, convolutionValue_A,
        convolutionValue_A, convolutionValue_A, convolutionValue_B, convolutionValue_B, convolutionValue_B, convolutionValue_A, convolutionValue_A
    ]

    let inputWeights:CIVector = CIVector(values: weightsArr, count: weightsArr.count)

    sourceCore = sourceCore
        .applyingFilter("CIColorControls", parameters: [kCIInputImageKey: sourceCore,
                                                        kCIInputSaturationKey: 0.0,
                                                        kCIInputBrightnessKey: brightnessVal,
                                                        kCIInputContrastKey: contrastVal])

    // transforms image to only show edges in black and white
    sourceCore = sourceCore
        .applyingFilter("CIConvolution7X7", parameters: [kCIInputImageKey: sourceCore,
                                                         kCIInputWeightsKey: inputWeights]).cropped(to: sourceCore.extent)

    // give camera image a black and white Noir effect
    var ciImage = ciImage
        .applyingFilter("CIPhotoEffectNoir", parameters: [kCIInputImageKey: ciImage])


    // make solid color
    let color = CIColor(red: 0.819, green: 0.309, blue: 0.309)
    let colFilter = CIFilter(name: "CIConstantColorGenerator")!
    colFilter.setValue(color, forKey: kCIInputColorKey)
    var solidColor = colFilter.value(forKey: "outputImage") as! CIImage
    solidColor = solidColor.cropped(to: ciImage.extent)

    // color should only be shown through outlines 
    // for some reason the input image is blue-ish
    sourceCore = sourceCore
        .applyingFilter("CIBlendWithMask", parameters: [
            kCIInputImageKey: ciImage, // black and white image
            kCIInputBackgroundImageKey: solidColor, // solid color
            kCIInputMaskImageKey:sourceCore]) // edge work image

    ciImage = sourceCore

    return ciImage

}
```

Here are the images every step of the way through the function:

My source, full-color image
[image: My source, full-color image]

This is what results when I apply the CIColorControls with 0 saturation and the 7x7 convolution. I use this for my mask to attempt to show orange through the black outline areas.
[image: resulting mask image]

This is the black and white after using the CIFilter "CIPhotoEffectNoir" that is used as the input image when blending it with the mask and solid color.
[image: black and white image]

The solid, orange color that I use as a background when blending with the mask.
[image: Solid orange color]

The resulting image after performing CIBlendWithMask that appears incorrect. 
[image: Result image]

First of all, I'd expect the background color only to appear where the outlines are on the mask image. Where the background color is, it appears orange instead of red, and the input image is blue-ish instead of strictly black and white.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is in the final blending step. When you call `sourceCore.applyingFilter(...)`, it will automatically set `sourceCore` as `inputImage` on that filter. And I'm not sure what happens when you re-define that in the `parameters`.

You could instead create the filter like this:

```
let blendFilter = CIFilter(name: "CIBlendWithMask", parameters: [
    kCIInputImageKey: ciImage,
    kCIInputBackgroundImageKey: solidColor,
    kCIInputMaskImageKey: sourceCore
])
return blendFilter.outputImage
```

By the way, you can create a solid color image much easier like this:

```
let solidColor = CIImage(color: color).cropped(to: ciImage.extent)
```

Comment: Thanks for the tip on the solid color. Unfortunately, the resulting image is the same by using your blendFilter code or changing the code so that it doesn't automatically set sourceCore as the inputImage.
Do you think this could have to do with setting values outside the bounds of expected values?

Comment: Interesting... Would you mind changing the blend filter to `CIBlendWithRedMask` and see how the result looks like?

Comment: Sure. It's exactly the same as the resulting image shown in my question.

Comment: Could you please try re-writing the parts that use `.applyingFilter` into something like above? I'm still tripping over this remark in the documentation: "This method, though convenient, is inefficient if used multiple times in succession. Achieve better performance by chaining filters without asking for the outputs of individual filters." Also setting the `kCIInputImageKey` parameter when using this method should be unneeded and might cause side effects?

Comment: The filter appears correctly if I replace the CIConvolution7X7 filter with a CIEdgeWork filter. (There's orange edges over a black and white image) The problem with CIEdgeWork is that it no longer works consistently the same between devices and iOS versions. Both the CIConvolution7X7 and CIEdgeWork filters result in a black and white image. I have a feeling that there is something wrong with the information that makes up the CIImage made from a CIConvolution7X7 filter that doesn't work correctly with a mask.

Comment: I have reported several problems over the years to Apple, but they have never decided to pursue to fix them. I think CIFilters should be marked as deprecated at this point.

Comment: Thanks for helping, but I figured out how to make it work. I needed to blend the result of the convolution with a white background with a CIColorDodgeBlendMode.

Comment: I wonder if the convolution maybe also affects the alpha channel and thereby creating those strange results when the alpha is pre-multiplied. Maybe you can try to  call `.settingAlphaOne(in: sourceCore.extent)` on the convolution result.

Comment: Frank, that is a really cool setting I never heard of. I tried applying it to the convolution filter I have set up there. It seems to have no effect. Any ideas?

Comment: I'm pretty clueless, to be honest. I would need to experiment with the code myself.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out, although I'm not sure why this works. I'm guessing it's a bug with Apple's tech. After the CIConvolution7X7, I needed to blend that black and white image with a white background using CIColorDodgeBlendMode or CILinearDodgeBlendMode.

Final code:

```
func sketch(with ciImage: CIImage) -> CIImage {

    var sourceCore = ciImage

    var convolutionValue_A:CGFloat = -0.0925937220454216
    var convolutionValue_B:CGFloat = -0.4166666567325592
    var convolutionValue_C:CGFloat = -1.8518532514572144
    var convolutionValue_D:CGFloat = 0.23148006200790405
    var convolutionValue_E:CGFloat = 4.5833334922790527
    var convolutionValue_F:CGFloat = 14.166666984558105

    var brightnessVal:CGFloat = 1.1041666269302368
    var contrastVal:CGFloat = 3.0555555820465088

    var weightsArr: [CGFloat] = [
        convolutionValue_A, convolutionValue_A, convolutionValue_B, convolutionValue_B, convolutionValue_B, convolutionValue_A, convolutionValue_A,
        convolutionValue_A, convolutionValue_B, convolutionValue_C, convolutionValue_C, convolutionValue_C, convolutionValue_B, convolutionValue_A,
        convolutionValue_B, convolutionValue_C, convolutionValue_D, convolutionValue_E, convolutionValue_D, convolutionValue_C, convolutionValue_B,
        convolutionValue_B, convolutionValue_C, convolutionValue_E, convolutionValue_F, convolutionValue_E, convolutionValue_C, convolutionValue_B,
        convolutionValue_B, convolutionValue_C, convolutionValue_D, convolutionValue_E, convolutionValue_D, convolutionValue_C, convolutionValue_B,
        convolutionValue_A, convolutionValue_B, convolutionValue_C, convolutionValue_C, convolutionValue_C, convolutionValue_B, convolutionValue_A,
        convolutionValue_A, convolutionValue_A, convolutionValue_B, convolutionValue_B, convolutionValue_B, convolutionValue_A, convolutionValue_A
    ]

    let inputWeights:CIVector = CIVector(values: weightsArr, count: weightsArr.count)

    sourceCore = sourceCore
        .applyingFilter("CIColorControls", parameters: [kCIInputImageKey: sourceCore,
                                                        kCIInputSaturationKey: 0.0,
                                                        kCIInputBrightnessKey: brightnessVal,
                                                        kCIInputContrastKey: contrastVal])

    // transforms image to only show edges in black and white
    sourceCore = sourceCore
        .applyingFilter("CIConvolution7X7", parameters: [kCIInputImageKey: sourceCore,

    let whiteCIColor = CIColor(red: 1, green: 1, blue: 1)

    let whiteColor = CIImage(color: whiteCIColor).cropped(to: ciImage.extent)

    // CIColorDodgeBlendMode, CILinearDodgeBlendMode

    sourceCore = sourceCore
            .applyingFilter("CIColorDodgeBlendMode", parameters: [kCIInputImageKey: sourceCore,
                                                                    kCIInputBackgroundImageKey: whiteColor])
                                                         kCIInputWeightsKey: inputWeights]).cropped(to: sourceCore.extent)

    // give camera image a black and white Noir effect
    var ciImage = ciImage
        .applyingFilter("CIPhotoEffectNoir", parameters: [kCIInputImageKey: ciImage])


    // make solid color
    let color = CIColor(red: 0.819, green: 0.309, blue: 0.309)
    let colFilter = CIFilter(name: "CIConstantColorGenerator")!
    colFilter.setValue(color, forKey: kCIInputColorKey)
    var solidColor = colFilter.value(forKey: "outputImage") as! CIImage
    solidColor = solidColor.cropped(to: ciImage.extent)

    // color is shown through outlines correctly, 
    // and image is black and white
    sourceCore = sourceCore
        .applyingFilter("CIBlendWithMask", parameters: [
            kCIInputImageKey: ciImage, // black and white image
            kCIInputBackgroundImageKey: solidColor, // solid color
            kCIInputMaskImageKey:sourceCore]) // edge work image

    ciImage = sourceCore

    return ciImage

}
```